# Что значит static в функциях и глобальных переменных?

Tags: c++, c

Что значит `static` в функциях и глобальных переменных? Я не говорю про статические методы, поля или что-то ещё связанное с ооп или статические локальные переменные в функциях. Вот это штука появилась уже с cи. Информацию про это я не нашел или непонятно рассказывали.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c

Comment: static означает, что область видимости такой переменной, объявленной  вне функции (или static функции), ограничена еденицей трансляции (файлом .c или .cpp) в которой она объявлена. static переменные внутри функции видны только внутри функции. Время жизни (т.е. время, в течении которого переменная сохраняет присвоенное ей ранее значение) таких переменных совпадает с временем существования всей программы (начиная от входа в main)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так нужно помечать переменные и функции внутри `.cpp`-файлов, которые используются только внутри этого файла, т.е. не объявлены в хедере. В C++ тот же эффект<sup>1</sup> имеет анонимный `namespace {...}`, но последний также действует на классы (что становится важно, если в них есть функции, статические переменные, и т.п.).

Это избавляет от ошибок линковки<sup>2</sup>, если имена переменных/функций совпадают в разных `.cpp`-файлах.

И, соответственно, к такой переменной/функции нельзя обратиться из другого файла, объявив ее там.

---

В комментариях мелькает "область видимости" и "storage duration", но на глобальных переменных/функциях `static` на них не влияет. Он влияет только на "linkage" (ставит "internal linkage" вместо "external linkage").

---

<sup>1</sup> Стандарт говорит, что эффект одинаковый, но на деле оказывается, что статические переменные/функции правда не видны линковщику, а содержимое анонимного неймспейса вроде как видно, хотя и помечено особым образом, чтобы эффект был тот же. Но это надо проверять.

<sup>2</sup> Ошибки не всегда явные. Если это два класса с одинаковым именем, и в них методы с одинаковым именем, и они `inline` (возможно неявно - потому что определены внутри тела класса), то линковщик может один из них выкинуть, и вместо него вызывать второй.